# Как использовать интерфейс IProjection

Tags: javascript, карты

Есть необходимость определения координат верхнего левого угла тайла с парковкой. Предполагаю, что нужно использовать метод **fromGlobalPixels()** интерфейса **IProjection**.
К сожалению, в данной документации я не нашел, как использовать IProjection. Подскажите, если кто знает. Спасибо!

Comment: Что такое IProjection?